# ajax html $_POST value from php function returns null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this html field

`<input type='text' name='newusername' value='' class='input-required' id='username'>`

and this is my php code in my `function.php`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_checkUsernameExistentVal', 'checkUsernameExistentVal');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_checkUsernameExistentVal', 'checkUsernameExistentVal');
function checkUsernameExistentVal(){
    $username = $_POST['newusername']; // it alwas null?
    // $username = 'existedusuer'; // works fine
    $val = checkCOntactUsernameExist($username);

    if ($val){
        $usernname_val= 'false';
    }else{
        $usernname_val = 'true';
    }
    // I concatenate `$username` to check if it has a value but it is always null?
    echo json_encode(array("validation" => $usernname_val.'-'.$val.'-'.$username));
    wp_die();

}
```

and this is my `scipt.js`.

```
jQuery('#username').blur(function() {
        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: ajax_url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                action: 'checkUsernameExistentVal',
                email: jQuery(this).val(),
            },
            async: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(data + ' | '+ data.validation);
                // data.validation value is always 'true--'??

            },

        });

    });
```

I have no idea why in my `function.php` in the function in `$_POST['newusername']` is always null.. do you have idea about this? seems my other code is working but this is not...

Comment: where is the value of newusername in the jquery?

Comment: my mistake hahah thanks MrTechie

Comment: maybe try changing your input text field's id to 'newusername'. in ajax your are passing id's not names of fields.

Answer (score 1):

You pass on on jquery email in a data so that variable you should pass on. 
because you pass the value in email.But getting value in $_POST['username']. so In that variable value is null.
$username = $_POST['**email**'];

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parameter in the function . You need to supply the variable posted to the function.

`function checkUsernameExistentVal($usernameParam)`